# Hessian of a loss function for a neural netwrok

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, machine-learning, neural-networks

Is a way to calculate the Hessian of the loss function in Mathematica. It's easy to define a loss function for neural nets but I couldn't figure out how to calculate the Hessian(more precisely I wanted to get access to eigenspectrum of Hessian). There are scientific papers, where they calculate Hessian of a loss using python(autograd (auto differentiation) algorithm).

The idea here to train a neural net for few epochs (say on a simple fully connected net or simplified LeNet) and then calculate the Hessian of the loss function.

Addendum:
Here's one such paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.07476.pdf

Comment: Could you share DOI of the paper you mentioned  for reference?

Comment: @Xminer Paper link added. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: AFAIK Wolfram's NN framework works on top of MXNet library, so until it fully supports 2nd order differentiation it's not possible. Relevant [issue](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/issues/10002).

Comment: @swish This is quite frustrating then. Mathematica for theoretical ML research seems quite restricting.

Comment: @psimeson because we can get 1st gradient,How about [an approximation of Hessian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_rank-one)?

Comment: How can you access the loss function (say after training for about 10 training rounds) in such a way that you can differentiate it?

Comment: @psimeson connect the net and loss function,train it with `NetTrain` and then get 1st Gradient with `NetGradient[{position of the layer,"Weights"}]`

Comment: Hessian support is awkward across all major frameworks, I've made a wrapper library to make it easier to compute in PyTorch -- https://github.com/cybertronai/autograd-lib