# Neural Network Automatic Differentiation ("Autograd")

Tags: neural-networks, mxnet-format

Automatic differentiation methods in general have been the [topic of past questions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1873/is-there-any-automatic-differentiation-package), but this is specifically about automatic differentiation of **neural networks**.

The motivation is an [old but useful trick for solving ODEs and PDEs](https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/9705023.pdf).  For example, in solving an ODE of the form: $u'(x) = f(x)$, where $f(x)$ is some known function and the goal is to find $u(x)$.  Let's assume $f(x) = 2x$ and $u(0) = 1$.  Then, we can implement neural network layers for our functions as follows:

```
Clear[u, f, g]

g = NetChain[ (*just some ansatz for the auxiliary function*)
  {LinearLayer[32], LogisticSigmoid, LinearLayer[32], LogisticSigmoid, LinearLayer[1]},
  "Input" -> "Real"]

(*create u from the auxiliary function g*)
u = With[{u0 = 1}, FunctionLayer[#*g[#] + u0 &]]

(*function we want to match (right hand side) *)
f = FunctionLayer[{2*#} &, "Input" -> "Real"]
```

and then fit $u$ by training a neural network function of the form:

```
(* finite difference approximation of du/dx *)
deriv[netU_] := With[{dx = 0.0001},
  NetChain[
   { FunctionLayer[{#, # + dx} &],(*given input x, compute x and x+dx*)
     NetMapOperator[netU],(*apply the u function to both inputs*)
     FunctionLayer[(#[[2]] - #1[[1]])/dx &]}, (*take the differences and divide by dx*)
   "Input" -> "Real"]
  ]

(* define a network where we minimize the difference between the learned du/dx and known f(x) *)
nn = NetGraph[
  {deriv[u], f, MeanSquaredLossLayer[]},
  {NetPort["Input"] -> {1, 2} -> 3}]

(* train on randomly generated points *)
trained = NetTrain[nn, RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 64], BatchSize -> 64]

(*extract the trained u function*)
trainedU = NetExtract[trained, {1, 2, "Net"}]
```

where `deriv` computes the derivative of the neural network function implementing $u(x)$ by finite-differences. This is fine in a simple 1D-example, but is inefficient as the dimensionality increases and opens up problems about the appropriate finite difference value to use.   **A better approach would be to compute the derivative of the network defining $u(x)$ with respect to its inputs, $x$, using so-called "autograd" methods.**

MXNet ([the underlying engine used by Mathematica](https://www.oreilly.com/content/apache-mxnet-in-the-wolfram-language/)) supports [calculating the gradient of networks with respect to inputs](https://mxnet.apache.org/versions/1.8.0/api/python/docs/tutorials/packages/autograd/index.html#Advanced:-Calculating-non-parameter-gradients) (and [is described in the MXNet Tutorial](https://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter01_crashcourse/autograd.html) on `mxnet.autograd`) So in principle this is doable. ([A related question on how to calculate the Hessian of a neural network in Mathematica was posted 2 years ago](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201421/hessian-of-a-loss-function-for-a-neural-netwrok), but at the time MXNet didn't support Hessians.)  **What's the best way to do this in Mathematica?**

My understanding is that this is *not quite* the functionality of [NetPortGradient](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NetPortGradient.html) (which takes a derivative with respect to particular specified data).  That is, while it allows for the following:

```
example = NetInitialize[u]
example[5, NetPortGradient["Input"]] (* computes the derivative at x=5 *)
```

it cannot be used to define new networks that can be used elsewhere:

```
FunctionLayer[example[#, NetPortGradient["Input"]] &] (*throws errors*)
```

Comment: In MxNET or PyTorch, you would implement this by backpropagating twice. Compute gradient g, let $m=g*e_1$, then compute gradient of $m$. This gives you the first row of the Hessian matrix. I wouldn't be surprised if Mathematica doesn't integrate this because frameworks didn't originally support double backprop (requires retain_graph=True arg). What kinds of layers were you planning to use? If it's LinearLayer/LogisticSigmoid/ReLU, I could throw together a simple implementation in pure Mathematica

Comment: To make this efficient with MxNET, Mathematica should implement a function like "NetPortHvp(input,vec)" which computes a Hessian-vector product. Internally it would issue two `.backwards()` calls, one with `retain_graph=True` and one without.

Comment: For anyone on Wolfram side reading this, here's an end-to-end implementation of Hessian vector product in PyTorch, which uses similar API to MxNet -- https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1VlirNQxEr3I36s7ra7wzYIapNpcB-l97#scrollTo=Z1dk3gI7QiSx&line=1&uniqifier=1